# Why gradle resolve dependencies in the module name order by default?

Tags: java, gradle

I've got three modules:

- `amodule`
- `bmodule`
- `cmodule`

There are integration-tests in all of these three modules. The `bmodule` is the base - it contains `BaseClass`, which I want to use in integration-tests in `amodule` and `cmodule`

The example of my project is on github: https://github.com/ljql/test-deps

I try to add dependency to integration-tests of `bmodule` in `amodule` and `cmodule`.
File `build.gradle` looks the same in modules `amodule` and `cmodule`

```
sourceSets {
    intTest {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test-integration/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/test-integration/resources'
        }
        compileClasspath += rootProject.project('bmodule').sourceSets.intTest.output
        runtimeClasspath += rootProject.project('bmodule').sourceSets.intTest.output
    }
}

configurations {
    intTestCompile {
        extendsFrom compile
    }
    intTestRuntime {
        extendsFrom runtime
    }
}

dependencies {
    intTestCompile project(path: ':bmodule', configuration:  'intTestCompile')
}
```

But when I try to build `amodule` I've got an error:

```
Build file '/test-deps/amodule/build.gradle' line: 10

A problem occurred evaluating project ':amodule'.
> Could not get unknown property 'intTest' for SourceSet container of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer.
```

The build of `cmodule`, which is the copy of `amodule`, is completed successfully.

The only difference between `amodule` and `cmodule` is in their names. The `amodule` precedes the `bmodule` and the `cmodule` followed by the `bmodule`

How can I specify a sequence of gradle resolve dependencies in my case? I want gradle to find out about the `bmodule` first and then about the `amodule` and the `cmodule`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the your `amdoule`'s build.gradle

```
preBuild.dependsOn ":bmodule:build"
```

Comment: still getting an error 'Could not get unknown property 'intTest' for SourceSet container of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer.'

Answer (score 0):

You have a project evaluation ordering problem. Since both `amodule` and `cmodule` expect to find specific components of `bmodule`, you need to ask Gradle to make sure `bmodule` has been evaluated first.

You can add in the build files of `amodule` and `cmodule` the following:

```
evaluationDependsOn(':bmodule')
```

While Gradle offers an API to resolve this, it will only work if you have no cycle, that is `bmodule` does not have dependencies on either `amodule` or `cmodule`, otherwise you will not be able to find a solution this way.

Another approach would be to leverage proper dependency resolution and declare that you want to share some test classes by having them [exposed as test-fixtures](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has three build phases:

- Initialization
- Configuration
- Execution

But the final result of resolving all dependencies appears only when gradle completes all three phases.

The error indicates a string in sourceSets - it is from the phase Configuration. At the start of this phase gradle knows nothing about any configurations in all modules. And gradle learns about the content of each module sequentially module-by-module. Of course when gradle considers the configuration of the `amodule` for the first time, it doesn't know anything about any configurations in the `bmudule`.

In the question I want to define compileClasspath and runtimeClasspath in confuguration `:amodule:intTest`. But there is nothing to stop me to define it in a custom task. Gradle will execute it on the third phase and the final compileClasspath and runtimeClasspath will contain the information from the `bmodule:intTest`

The result build.gradle of `amodule`:

```
sourceSets {
    intTest {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test-integration/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/test-integration/resources'
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    intTestCompile {
        extendsFrom compile
    }
    intTestRuntime {
        extendsFrom runtime
    }
}

task intTest {
    sourceSets.intTest.compileClasspath += rootProject.project('bmodule').sourceSets.intTest.output
    sourceSets.intTest.runtimeClasspath += rootProject.project('bmodule').sourceSets.intTest.output
}
```